# Is this definition of local continuity (with open sets) accurate?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition

I am looking for a definition of local continuity (continuity at a point) with open sets.

A quick google search has led me to [this](http://lipas.uwasa.fi/%7Etsottine/talks/Paris2008.pdf) but I could not understand the fourth slide...

But before the google search, I had invented up a little definition that could be reasonnably true. It is the following:

Let's pick a function $f$ and a point $(x_0,y_0)$ of the function.

> If some set in the domain is:
>
> - the preimage (by the function $f$) of an open interval (in the codomain) containing the ordinate of the point ($y_0$)
> - a set which contains the $(x_0,0)$ point
> - open

> THEN, the function $f$ is continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$

What do you think of this local continuity definition? Is it correct?

Comment: where is your function defined and where lies its image ?

Comment: Well it has a domain and a codomain. But I can't say anything else

Comment: you are talking about intervalls and taking a point $(x_0, 0)$ so you seem to be considering $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$, but it is unclear

Comment: Ah ok, no it's a one variable function, with real value ($\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$)

Comment: $(x_0, 0)$ means that it is the point with x coordinate $x_0$ and ordinate $y=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notations are a little woobly:

- In the second bullet, your set $f^{-1}(I)\subset\Bbb R$ must containt $x_0,$ not $(x_0,0).$
- $f$ will be continuous at the point $x_0,$ not $(x_0,y_0).$
- $f^{-1}(I)$ itself may not be open.

But the more important point is the lack of quantifiers. *Every* function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ s.t. $f(x_0)=y_0$ satisfies your condition, without necessarily being continuous at $x_0.$ Here is a sensible formulation:

> *For every* real open interval $I\ni y_0,$ the preimage $f^{-1}(I)$ *contains* some open set containing $x_0.$

However, this is the usual definition of continuity at $x_0.$ The notion of *local* continuity at $x_0$ defined in the *fifth* slide of your link, which I didn't know before, is (equivalent to) a slight modification of the previous definition:

> There exists an open interval $J\ni x_0$ such that $x_0\in\bar J$ and for every real open interval $I\ni y_0,$ the preimage $f^{-1}(I)$ contains the intersection of $J$ with some open set containing $x_0.$

Comment: I don't really understand why it's "contains some open" and not "is open"

Comment: Look at the example on the 12th slide: the indicator function of $[0,+\infty)$ is locally continuous at every point, but for $x_0\ge0$ (hence $y_0=1$), the preimage $[0,+\infty)$ of $I=(1/2,3/2)$ is not open.

Comment: But I feel more comfortable with the usual notion of continuity at $x_0,$ to give you a better counterexample in that case: let $f(x)=x$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ else. $f$ is continuous at $0$ but for any open interval $I\ni0$ distinct from $\Bbb R,$ $f^{-1}(I)=I\cup(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$ is not open.